# KeyListener source

Tags: java, listener, keylistener

How can I access component to which the KeyListener is associated within the KeyListener itself?

I have to create a universal keylistener which would be associated with whole array of JTextAreas, to be exact, and I need to access each and everyone of them from it.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? Can you give us some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `KeyEvent` comes with the component originating the `KeyEvent` "attached," which can be accessed using its [`getComponent` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentEvent.html#getComponent%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

You can create your KeyListener inside the class where the component resides, as an inner class.

A second option would be to pass the component as an argument to the constructor of your KeyListener but this increases the coupling.

Actually, inner classes have been added to Java having as one of the reasons these kinds of situations.